# FaceTime HD Camera not working on MacBook Pro 2016

Tags: macbook-pro, camera, facetime, webcam

I have a MacBook Pro 2016 (with Touch Bar), yesterday I installed [Snap Camera](https://snapcamera.snapchat.com/) (by Snapchat) and it worked while I was on a video call. Afterwards, when the call had ended the green camera light got stuck on.

I force quit all apps but it stayed on, I then restarted the Mac and the light persisted through the whole reboot. So I then shutdown the Mac and it turned off.

Since then, camera has not worked. I reset the SMC, PRAM and am currently waiting for macOS to reinstall (didn't wipe data).

It sounds like there is a hardware issue to me, but just seems like a funny coincidence that it occurred immediately after finishing a video call where I had just used Snap Camera for the first time.

My Apple Care has now expired, so guess I'm out of luck? Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't a hardware issue. Third party apps can cause issues with Apple hardware. Do you have Bootcamp installed? If you do, does it work in Windows 10? Try changing your privacy settings.

Comment: I don't have it installed unfortunately. I wasn't worried at first, I was sure a SMC reset would fix it. I've uninstalled the third party app now and still can't get it to work - tried safe mode too. Also ran Apple Diagnostics and it found nothing. Praying it is a software problem, but I'm almost out of ideas.

Comment: Try checking if you can reinstall drivers. Also try installing the original version of macOS that came with your computer (not wiping everything). Check this: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac

Comment: Also check out this: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7529179